# Android Toast Context Conundrum

Tags: android, this, toast, android-context

I am having some trouble with my toast context for my submit button. I've tried `setApplicationContext()` and `MyActivity.this` but neither works... and I can't quite work it out. Anyone have any ideas?

The bit I'm having trouble with is:

```
Toast.makeText(CustomItemizedOverlay.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**EDIT**
Turns out the problem wasn't just the context, the solution "context" works fine if a public context variable is stated in the class. It was in fact the some other part of the code that caused it to crash.

Comment: try `getBaseContext()` and 'getApplicationContext ()'

Comment: hi there, getBaseContext() throws up the same error as getApplicationContext() "The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){"

Comment: use `context.getApplicationContext()` and your code if fine

Comment: Try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449675/nullpointerexception-calling-activity-using-dialogfragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Toast.makeText(CustomItemizedOverlay.this, allanswers[whichButton], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(context, allanswers[whichButton], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Assuming you've used the constructor that sets the `context` parameter.

Comment: hi there, context seems to get rid of the error, but when i click the submit button it crashes the app. I presume I haven't used the constructor to set the context parameter?

Comment: hi Chris, I'm a bit of a java beginner. Can you point me in the rough direction of what to look up please?

Comment: @kel196 Can you post the code that instantiates the above code? I.e where is this code used?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the other code, I hope it is the right one!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), allanswers[whichButton], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

instead of

```
Toast.makeText(CustomItemizedOverlay.this, allanswers[whichButton], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

just replace `CustomItemizedOverlay.this` with `context.getApplicationContext()` and `private Context context` with `Context context;`

Comment: ....that also doesn't work. i've added my other bit of code that instantiates it. maybe that will provide clues to the solution?

Comment: see my edit if it will not work then use `Applcation` class to create a global object of Context