# NullPointerException calling activity using DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am in the process of converting my dialogs to `DialogFragments`.  I'm following the instructions [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) but it looks like they are using it in an `Activity` and I'm using it in a `Fragment`.  I've created the `Listener` back to my fragment, but when I call `getActivity()` it is throwing a `NullPointerException`:

```
public class DialogTextAdd extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

    private EditText mText;

    public interface DialogTextAddListener {
        void onDialogTextAdd(final String inputText);
    }

    public DialogTextAdd() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit, container);
        mText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.Text_add);
        getDialog().setTitle("Add Text");

        // Show soft keyboard automatically
        mText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        mText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {
        if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {

            new MyFragment().onDialogTextAdd(mText.getText().toString()); //think this is my problem
            this.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements DialogKeywordAddListener
{
    @Override
    public void onDialogTextAdd(final String text) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity act) {
    super.onAttach(act);
}


}
```

Using this code got it to work:

```
    MyFragment mf = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", mText.getText().toString());
    mf.setArguments(args);

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mf, "my_fragment").commit();
```

Comment: Is `getActivity()` null when you call it?

Comment: yes it is.......(had to add those for fill 12 characters)

Comment: You're constantly making a new Fragment every time `onEditorAction()` is called. And all your new Fragment does is make a Toast. How necessary is this sub-Fragment?

Comment: Well there's more going on in `onDialogTextAdd` (some database calls), but I left that out.

Comment: Not sure, I was just following Google's documenation regarding `DialogFragments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you use `getSupportFragmentManager()` and add (`.add(fragment, tag)`) the new instance of your fragment to the `FragmentTransaction` by doing `.beginTransaction()` and then call `commit()`? I guess thats what you are trying to do.

`getActivity()` returns `null` since your new Fragment instance is not attached to the Activity (native `FragmentActivity/Activity` or `SherlockFragmentActivity/SherlockActivity`, whatever it is).

Do some readings about using fragments. Instantiantion of the fragment is not enough. Find about underlying operations after instantiation.

Comment: I am still wrapping my head around `Fragments`, and this might be obvious based on the name, but a `DialogFragment` is handled like a `Fragment` of it's own?

Comment: Yes, your right. SDK DialogFragment implementation still uses fragmentmanager for showing/dismissing the fragment (dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

Instead of:

```
getActivity()
```

**EDIT:**

Use this method

```
@Override
public void onAttach(SupportActivity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, that doesn't work because `getActivity()` is null so calling `getApplicationContext()` on it results in another NPE.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually had that in there already, but didn't include it.  I'll update my OP

Comment: @KrisB try to change with `SupportActivity` there.