# Calling Internet Detect void from another class

Tags: java, android

I am making Internet Detector class so when internet is off, its shows a Dialog with two options, one is to exit the app and another is to refresh the void who is checking internet. And app force closes when clicking refresh. Take a look at the code.

Fragment class

```
public void check(){
    DetectConnection dc = new DetectConnection(getActivity());
    if(dc.isConnectedToInternet()==true) {
        String url = "...";
        new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url);
    } else {
        FragmentManager ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        MyAlertDialogWIndow alert = new MyAlertDialogWIndow();
        alert.show(ft, "Alert");
    }
}
```

MyAlertDialogWIndow class

```
public class MyAlertDialogWIndow extends DialogFragment {

    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    DetectConnection detectConnection;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OnClickListener positiveClick = new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {   

            fragment2.check();
        }
    };
}

   OnClickListener negativeClick = new OnClickListener() {  
  @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


 }
 };

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
 builder.setMessage("Device is not connected to the internet. Check your connection and click refresh");
 builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", negativeClick);
 builder.setPositiveButton("Refresh", positiveClick);
 builder.setTitle("No Connection");
 Dialog dialog = builder.create();
 return dialog;
   }
```

DetectConnecion class

```
public class DetectConnection {

private Context _context;

public DetectConnection(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
           ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)                                           _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
}
```

errors

at

`com.example.example.DetectConnection.isConnectedToInternet(DetectConnection.java:16)`

which is `public class MyAlertDialogWIndow extends DialogFragment`

and `.Fragment2.check(Fragment2.java:93)`  which is   `if(dc.isConnectedToInternet()==true)`

full logcat

```
 12-12 14:48:31.445: W/dalvikvm(3211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211): java.lang.NullPointerException
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):at                                                              com.example.example.DetectConnection.isConnectedToInternet(DetectConnection.java:16)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at com.example.example.Fragment2.check(Fragment2.java:93)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at com.example.example.MyAlertDialogWIndow$1.onClick(MyAlertDialogWIndow.java:27)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
 12-12 14:48:31.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: if(dc.isConnectedToInternet()==true)

Comment: How does `isConnectedToInternet()` look like?

Comment: @SandraMladenovic your `createDilalog` returns nothing

Comment: @SandraMladenovic  `public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)` a dialog. see the return type

Comment: Sorry, i didn't posted the  whole code  i did return dialog;  i posted only code for positive button from onCreateDialog. So return is not problem. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `getActivity()` on a `Fragment` that hasn't been attached to an `Activity`.

When you instantiate your `Fragment` class as follows

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
```

It will return `null` for `getActivity()`.  Instead of instantiating your `Fragment` there, I would suggest calling a `FragmentTransaction` from the `Activity` that you plan on using it with and attach the `Fragment` first.

**Edit**

Another, possibly easier, option would be to make the Internet Detection method a part of your `Activity` rather than your `Fragment`.  That way you could just do the following:

```
OnClickListener positiveClick = new OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {   

        ((YourActivityName)getActivity()).check();
    }
};
```

Comment: I did this ((Fragment2)getActivity()).check();  but Cannot cast from Activity to Fragment2

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.  You put the `check()` method in your `Activity` instead of your `Fragment`.  You can't cast `Fragments` to `Activities`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `getActivity()` doesn't return null? Here:

```
DetectConnection dc = new DetectConnection(getActivity());
```

I think this is faling because the context (i.e. activity is `null`):

```
ConnectivityManager connectivity = 
   (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

This might for instance happen, if your fragment is currently not attached to an activity.

Only other option would be that one of `info[i]` equals `null` - rather unlikely, I think.

**p.s.** check for instance [this sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
                          implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener{
    ...

    public void showNoticeDialog() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        DialogFragment dialog = new NoticeDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
    }
```

So you see you have to provide the fragment manager in the first call. Otherwise `getActivity()` will be `null`, what can rsult in a NPE here as well:

```
public void check(){
    ...
    } else {
        FragmentManager ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager(); // getActivity() might return null 
        MyAlertDialogWIndow alert = new MyAlertDialogWIndow();
        alert.show(ft, "Alert");
    }
```

Comment: But dialog is showing up and working when i start app with no connection but when i want to refresh  it force closes.

Comment: Not an issue so far - `check()` is only called if a button is clicked (see `onClick()`) - or do I miss something?

Comment: no, check() is first called on public View onCreateView, and its work, but its called to in Dialog class  onClick and this is where its force closes

Comment: Guess the `onCreateView` belongs to another fragment that is already attached to an activity - so you get no issue there. But your `DialogFragment` isn't attached yet. Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449675/nullpointerexception-calling-activity-using-dialogfragment

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your code,

```
public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
    this line can be corrected, using my code below:
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)

ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); OR
NetworkInfo[] info = connMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
```